# Extract String between 2 dollar sign

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have string which contains a variable. But i need to replace the `name` with what i have in the db.

`string text = "hello $$name$$, good morning"`

How can i extract the `name` by using `Regex`?

This only works if i have single `$`

`var MathedContent = Regex.Match((string)bodyObject, @"\$.*?\$");`

Comment: What language is this? `/\$\$([^$])\$\$/` should match that

Comment: I am using C# .

Comment: If you plan to use the `name` to get some values you  have elsewhere, you may consider `Regex.Replace((string)bodyObject, @"\$\$(\w+)\$\$", m => dct[m.Groups[1].Value])`, but you will need to have a `dct` dictionary ready with all possible keys.

Comment: Do you need to replace whole `$$name$$` or only `name` and leave `$$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define regular expression, `"(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)"` with 3 different groups:

```
 "(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)"
 ^^^^^^|^^^^^|^^^^^^
    $1    $2    $3
```

and then if you need just simple replacement you can do something like this:

```
string replacedText = Regex
    .Replace("hello $$name$$, good morning", @"(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)", "replacement");
//hello replacement, good morning
```

or combine with the other groups

```
string replacedText = Regex
    .Replace("hello $$name$$, good morning", @"(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)", "$1replacement$3");
//hello $$replacement$$, good morning
```

On the other hand, if you need more control you could do something like this(tnx to [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679074/extract-string-between-2-dollar-sign#comment96147314_54679074)):

```
IDictionary<string, string> factory = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"name", "replacement"}
};

string replacedText = Regex.Replace(
    "hello $$name$$, good morning",
    @"(?<b>\$\$)(?<replacable>.*?)(?<e>\$\$)",
    m => m.Groups["b"].Value + factory[m.Groups["replacable"].Value] + m.Groups["e"].Value);
//hello $$replacement$$, good morning
```

Comment: I think you could also use 2 capturing groups `(\$\$).*?(\$\$)` and use `$1replacement$2` in the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is slightly ambigous as to whether you want to replace the entire `$$name$$` or find the string between the dollars.

Here's working code for both:

Replace $$name$$ with Bob

```cs
    string input = "hello $$name$$, good morning";
    var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\$\$\w+\$\$)", "Bob");
    Console.WriteLine($"replaced: {replaced}");
```

Prints `replaced: hello Bob, good morning`

Extract name from string:

```cs
    string input = "hello $$name$$, good morning";
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\$\$(\w+)\$\$").Groups[1].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"match: {match}");
```

Prints `match: name`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture the text between the `$$` delimiters but exclude the `$$` themselves, you can use [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<=\$\$).*?(?=\$\$)`

Lookarounds are zero-length assertions (much like `\b`) that match characters but do not include them in the result. `(?<=XXX)YYY` matches `YYY` on condition that it's *preceded* by `XXX`. Similarly, `YYY(?=ZZZ)` matches `YYY` on condition that it's *followed* by `ZZZ`.

```
var match = Regex.Match("hello $$name$$, good morning", @"(?<=\$\$).*?(?=\$\$)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);   // outputs "name"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "hello $$name$$, good morning";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\$\$)(.*?)(?=\$\$)");

Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(input).Groups[1].Value);
```

Result:

```
name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the negation set, `[^ ]`. Such as `[^$]+` where we will match until the next `$`.

```
string text = "hello $$name$$, good morning";

Regex.Replace(text, @"\$\$[^$]+\$\$", "Jabberwocky");
```

Result:

```
 hello Jabberwocky, good morning
```

---

More verbose but easier to read without escaping, pattern `[$]{2}[^$]+[$]{2}`.